# How to change password in django without using authentication system?

Tags: python, django

I want to change password without using authentication system.The password is getting changed but I am not getting success message but instead I am getting error as `ValueError: The view books.views.password_change didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead`

views.py,

```
def password_change(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_password = request.POST.get('pwd2')
        user=request.user  
        try:  
            u = User.objects.get(username=user)
            u.set_password(new_password)
            u.save() #problem line
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Password Changed')  
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'User Does not exist')   
    else:
        return render(request,"password_change.html",{})
```

My template file,

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div>
           <p>Username:{{request.user}}</p>
           <input type="password" name="pwd1" placeholder="Password">
           <input type="password" name="pwd2" placeholder="Confirm Password">
           <button type="submit">Update Password</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

url file,

```
url(r'^password_change/$',views.password_change,name='password_change'),
```

Comment: Well, what response do you want to return when the method *is* `POST`? What was unclear about the error message?

Comment: Just a success message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're not returning anything in that `try` block. A `message` is **not** an `HttpResponse` as you suppose.

You should explicitly return an `HttpResponse` that will indicate that the password has been changed successfully.

Note that every branch in your view must return something usable. So the `except` block will equally need to be fixed.

Comment: @Bhanukiran - If you have a new question, you should raise it as a new question (with what you tried and researched). If this answer solved *this* question, you should consider accepting it.